# ExecuteScript in a random tab that is not part of the chrome extension send result back to background javascript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to check the html of an element of a

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab_id,{code: 'sendRequestToBackground(document.getElementById('important_val').innerHTML); '},

function(){

});
```

I want to be able to get this value from my background script, I saw a lot of examples with `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener` because all the examples is for working from the extension popup.html to background script and vice-versa.

But I open a brand new tab, change the URL, and I want to get a value of a field that (which btw is generated via Javascript) belongs to this random tab.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inject your code to a random tab, do this:

1. Be sure to have [permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) to "tabs" and "<all_urls>" in your manifest.json
2. Get all tabs using [chrome.tabs.query](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query)
3. Pick random tab using `Math.random()`
4. Inject the code using [chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)
5. In the incjected code call [chrome.extension.sendRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest)
6. On the background page receive the message using [chrome.extension.onRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest)